# C function pointer confusion, what is meant by "pointer level of the variable"?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

This is the code:

```
char *(*strcpy_ptr)(char *dst, const char *src); Pointer to strcpy-like function
```

And the [tutorial](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#function_pointers) says:

> Note the parentheses around *strcpy_ptr in the above declaration.
>   These separate the asterisk indicating return type (char *) from the
>   asterisk indicating the pointer level of the variable (*strcpy_ptr —
>   one level, pointer to function).

I'm lost on this - where is the "function pointer" and what is the "pointer level" ?

Comment: This one - http://boredzo.org/pointers/#function_pointers , hmm maybe I'm not using the best tutorial?

Comment: He might mean pointers (`*`), pointer of pointers (`**`), etc.

Comment: @Adel: well, at least is very graphic "3 - 2 = 1" puts a new spin on the term "pointer arithmetic"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a variable `strcpy_ptr`. You want this variable to be a pointer to a function returning a `char*`. If you did it without the parentheses this way:

```
char **strcpy_ptr(char *dst, const char *src);
```

It would be the *prototype* of a function that returns a `char**` - not what you want. The parentheses are to group one star with the *variable*, and seperate the star from the *return type*.

Remember that pointers are declared like this:

```
T *var;
```

Where `T` is some type. The more stars you add, the more levels of indirection you add before you finally get to the actual `T`. So `char **c` would be a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. It's the same thing for function pointers: `T` is `char*`, and `*var` must be seperated by parentheses, because C is ignorant of white space. C just added a little extra syntax to specify what kind of and how many arguments the function takes that is pointed to by the pointer. This is just part of the way C works.

Answer (score 1):

Without the parens, you would have: **strcpy_ptr

This is a pointer to a pointer or double indirection.  I think 'one level' means there is just one level of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

@Adel: all most all parts of the above comments make some sense (with few picky exceptions like C doesn't understand white space), still I will suggest you to read "C programming language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, 2nd edition, chapter 5.11 and specially chapter 5.12 (Complicated expressions-p122): you will find good number of complicated examples and it is important to understand each one of them.

specially, understanding the differences between:

1. char (* (* x()) [] ) ()

and

2.char (*(*x[])())[]

cforfun.

Comment: @Adel: BTW, when its get too complicated you will need some rules to match the parenthesis and how to swing between right to left starting from the variable: there are many places in web where it is explained, this one is one of them: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: (1) contains a syntax error (one opening parenthesis more than closing parenthesis – verified with http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: @Felix Dombek: yes, fixed it! for some reason when i typing a c syntax the edit window doesn't accept all the characters unless i am putting some blanks..thanks for pointing out and the URL, its really useful!